# How to unquote string in R to access column in data table

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose I have a data.table called mysample. It has multiple columns, two of them being `weight` and `height`. I can access the weight column by typing: 
`mysample[,weight]`

But when I try to write `mysample[,colnames(mysample)[1]]` I cannot see the elements of `weight`. Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: I think it should be `mysample[,colnames(mysample)[1]] `. Parentheses for the `colnames()` function.

Comment: @Abdou. I actually meant that originally. It still does not work because I believe weight has quotations.

Comment: You could try to rename the column first before running that code again. `colnames(mysample)[1] <- "weight"`

Comment: But as long as you're using `colnames()` it should not matter how the column name is formatted, I don't think.

Comment: It works when I use use mysample[,weight] but not mysample[,"weight"]

Comment: Perhaps it's because it's a data table not a data frame?

Comment: I really suggest you go through the [HTML vignettes here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started).

Comment: @Arun In the second vignette, why does part b) the := operator, have an example with DT, valA, valB? Those columns are never defined. Am I missing a vignette. (I worked through the Introduction page)

Comment: That's the definition - it defines the possible ways of using it. We'll use it in the next section after learning how to use it (will clarify this in the vignette).

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to section 1.1 of data.table FAQ: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.pdf

colnames(mysample)[1] evaluates to character vector "weight", and the 2nd argument J in data.table is an expression which is evaluated within the scope of DT. Thus, "weight" evaluates to character vector "weight" itself and you can't see the elements of *"weight"* column. To actually subset *"weight"* column you should try:

```
mysample[,colnames(mysample)[1], with = F]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax should work for data frames. `data.table` has its unique rules.

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:3, b=4:6)
df
  a b
1 1 4
2 2 5
3 3 6

df[,"a"]
[1] 1 2 3
df$a
[1] 1 2 3
df[,1]
[1] 1 2 3
df[,colnames(df)[1]]
[1] 1 2 3
```